# Laravel 5 - webpage showing source code when i hit the back button on my browser

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Good morning,

I have one problem, that i can't figure out why's happening. I have a website in Laravel 5 and it's working great, except if i hit the back button.

If i'm on one of the pages and hit back to return to the index, for example, the page won't render, just shows the source code on the browser, then if i refresh it, it will render again.

Anyone knows if this could be some kind of Laravel bug or some configuration i messed up?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post some of your code here for others to generate the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

please give a screenshot of the error page then it will help the developer to figure out the problem.
**But I think may be you did not write any route for the back button**

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the help, but i figure out the problem.

I had this line inside my <head>

 <link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-color" type="text/css" href="#"/>

After remove it, stoped showing the source code when i go back on my website.

Anyway, if anyone knows why this happens, please explain me, i would like to understand. :)